# Can we edit sas7bcat files using proc sql

Tags: sas

I am trying to explore if we can create user defined formats using `proc sql` instead of `proc format`? Is it achievable. Can we edit formats catalog using `proc sql`? I tried to query it, but i could not. Does anyone know if that's achievable ?
Thanks!

Comment: A bit more details could be informative. What exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to create formats but with a limitation of using only proc sql. I don't know if that even achievable?

Answer (score 2):

No, I think `proc format` is your only option for creating formats, and for editing catalogue files you can only use `proc catalog`.

Answer (score 2):

I think User user667489 is correct... however there is a work-around, which might be useful.

Your can create classifying variables via application of `case`-logic:

```
proc sql outobs=30; 
    select case 
        when 10 <= vehicle_type or vehicle_type < 20 then 'passenger' 
        when 20 < vehicle_type or  vehicle_type < 30 then  'lcv'
    end as type 
    from begin; 
quit;
```

See more from [Documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/fedsqlref/67364/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n09kux4rsaumc8n17ubglbf83r98.htm)

**Edit:**

Lets see if I can work out better example. For sake of argument, I define that we're interested in cheap spotrscars/SUVS and want to create categorical variable to detect any combination of these.

```
proc sql outobs=30; 
    create table results as
    select   type 
            ,case when type in('SUV' 'Sports') then 1 
                  else 0 
                  end as wanted_type
            ,MSRP
            ,case when MSRP < 30000 then 'cheap'
                  when MSRP > 45000 then 'Expensive'
                  else 'inconclusive' 
                  end as price_range 
            from sashelp.cars;
quit;
```

At this point we have the original data and new grouping variables *wanted-type*  and *price range* like below. Of course, you don't have to select the original value, but in this example it's to show the result and original.

```
Type   wanted_type  MSRP    price_range 
SUV    1           $36,945  inconclusive 
Sedan  0           $23,820  cheap 
Sedan  0           $26,990  cheap 
Sedan  0           $33,195  inconclusive 
Sedan  0           $43,755  inconclusive 
Sedan  0           $46,100  Expensive 
Sports 1           $89,765  Expensive 
Sedan  0           $25,940  cheap
```

Comment: Sorry @pinegulf, did not understand that, are you saying we can query sas catalogs using case statements?

Comment: @Rhea Added further explanation/example.